# Get element from SWT page and do click on it

Tags: javascript, java, swt

I used SWT Browser in Java project.

I load page in SWT Browser. I can not edit this page.

I want put mouse on `<div>...</div>` element (which looks as example below, he has changing class name from 'active' to 'activeHover' when mouse is on it) and store them in Java object, then manage click on it by Java application.

```
<div class="active">
    <div id="bid_3" class="bid hasListeners" title="SELL">
        <span class="direction">Sell</span>
        <span class="indicative price">Indicative</span>
        <div class="minmax price">
            <span class="minmaxTitle">min</span><span id="minBidPrice_3"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="bidPrice_3" class="price indicativeValue">7041.2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used Filter to get mouse event on SWT Browser display

```
display.addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println(">> MouseDown " + event);
    }
});
```

This 'event' which is returned on event have only this informations:

```
>> MouseDown Event {type=3 Browser {} time=344032562 data=null x=477 y=1302 width=0 height=0 detail=0}
```

But how get this element and do click on them when I want ? I must delegate to click action from Java code.

Comment: You should read this: [Browser Tales – Java to JavaScript and vice versa with the SWT Browser Widget](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/)

Comment: But I cant modify page with this <div> element. I think about get this element and come back with action on them ? Something like that: Click on element in SWT Browser page -> remember this element int Java -> when I want, call doClick() on this element by Java code

Comment: You could try to call `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` with the mouse position by calling `Browser#evaluate()`.

Comment: @Baz where I should execute `Browser#evaluate()` ?

Comment: In the `SWT.MouseDown` listener. Use the event's `x` and `y` position.

Comment: Ok but on Java side I do not have 'document' element. It is possible to get it from shell/display ?

Comment: That's why you should call `browser.evaluate("document.elementFromPoint(" + event.x + "," + event.y + ")")`. You may need to adjust the `x` and `y` position based on the webpage's scroll position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126337/discussion-between-czarek-and-baz).